# Combine two selectors in slice().hide() function - jQuery

Tags: jquery, hide, slice

How do I consolidate this to one statement? The elements do not have id's or unique names, just going off the selector itself.

```
$("article").slice(1).hide();
$("main h1").slice(1).hide();
```

*** EDIT ***

GaetanoM's answer worked ...

```
$('article:gt(0), main h1:gt(0)').hide()
```

I tried something similar to what Matiboux suggested (as well as what he/she suggested, obviously) ...

```
$("article, main h1").slice(1).hide();
```

Follow up question - Can someone explain why the second one there didn't work? Seems more straight forward. It hid the article entirely.

Comment: Second does not work due to slice only working on (1) element. You can look at it like it finds all the elements first then looks at them as 1 group. Grabbing just the first one from that group. And the first one is hiding everything but the first. The seconds is hiding only the first. Im guessing you only have 1 article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [combine](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) selectors using [:gt() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) and remembering that [.slice( start )](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) means:

> Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices. the parameter is an integer indicating the 0-based position.

The snippet is:

```js
$('article:gt(0), main h1:gt(0)').hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<article>
    articol 1
</article>
<article>
    articol 2
</article>
<article>
    articol 3
</article>


<main>
    <h1>h1</h1>
</main>
<main>
    <h1>h2</h1>
</main>
<main>
    <h1>h3</h1>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think something like `$("article, main h1").slice(1).hide();` should do the trick. This works like CSS rules.

Comment: What if there are 2 elements, one of <article> and one of <main><h1>. This will only affect the first one.